# View chrome source in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul, chromebug

It would be extremely helpful for developing Firefox extensions if I could see the source of, e.g., chrome://browser/content/browser.xul *with overlays applied*. Is there a way to do this? [Chrome List](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4453/) and "View Source" show only the base structure, [ChromeBug](http://getfirebug.com/releases/chromebug/) requires restarting the browser and isn't too easy to get working.

Comment: Does the DOM inspector not show the overlays applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6622/), and I highly recommend pairing that with [Inspect Context](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3276/) which adds an "Inspect" option to the right-click menu of almost everything, much like the "Inspect Element" option of Firebug.